# PHP: Code works on PHP 7.0 but not in PHP 7.1

Tags: php, arrays, object, mysqli

I have the following code:

```
function qSELECT($query, $object = NULL){
    global $link;
    $result = mysqli_query($link, $query);
    $return = [];
    if($result){
        $num = mysqli_num_rows($result);
        for ($i=0; $i<$num; $i++){
            if(!is_null($object)){
                $row = mysqli_fetch_object($result);
            }else{
                $row = mysqli_fetch_array($result);
            }
            $return[$i]=$row;
        }
    }
    return $return;
}


function getAll($table){
    $query = "SELECT * FROM ".$table;
    $result = qSELECT($query);
    return $result;
}
```

And another file which calls getALL to display a table with the values in the table.

```
<?php
        $Draseis = getAll("Draseis");   
        if($Draseis) foreach ($Draseis as $Draseis):
                ?>
        <tr>
        <td><?php echo $Draseis['title']?></td>
        <td><?php echo $Draseis['title']?></td>
        <td><?php echo $Draseis['text']?></td>
        <td><?php echo $Draseis['image1']?></td>
        <td><?php echo $Draseis['image2']?></td>
        <td><?php echo $Draseis['image3']?></td>
        <td><?php echo $Draseis['image4']?></td>
        <td><?php echo $Draseis['image5']?></td>


        <td><a href="edit-draseis.php?act=edit&id=<?php echo $Draseis['id']?>"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-edit"></i></a></td>
        <td><a href="save.php?act=delete&id=<?php echo $Draseis['id']?>&cat=Draseis" onclick="return navConfirm(this.href);"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-trash"></i></a></td>
        </tr>
<?php endforeach; ?>
```

In PHP 7.0 the return value ($Draseis) in qSELECT is an "Array" when I echo it, and everything works meaning all 7 records are displayed.

In PHP 7.1 however, when I echo the return value ($Draseis) I get 7 x A as a result "AAAAAAA" and no records are displayed.

Any idea why?

Comment: Isn't it an array? If you are trying to echo an array you should get an error. What errors do you see?

Comment: Thats my problem. None. When I echo the Array in 7.0 I get the text "Array", in 7.1 I get "AAAAAAA"  and if I echo only $Draseis['0] I get A. So every A is a record since there are 7 records in the database. My problem is that in PHP 7.1 it returns A instead of the row that I can later address with $Draseis['title'] for example.

Answer (score -1):

Found the Answer. I had to add MYSQLI_ASSOC

```
    if(!is_null($object)){
        $row = mysqli_fetch_object($result,MYSQLI_ASSOC);
    }else{
        $row = mysqli_fetch_array($result,MYSQLI_ASSOC);
    }
```

Comment: `mysqli_fetch_object` only takes one argument.

Comment: Not in the procedural style  https://www.w3schools.com/php/func_mysqli_fetch_array.asp